# Is insert order preserved on queries in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm planning on using dynamodb as a data store for chat logs.  Is insert order preserved in any queries that I do against it if I don't state a range order and just set `ScanIndexForward = false`?

I would just want to query for the tail `100 messages` for a given hash and want to make sure they are coming back chronologically descending based on when the record was inserted.

Comment: You can also use a DynamoDB-based atomic counter (update_item with UpdateExpression) to populate the sort key. This also prevents time collisions.

Answer (score 3):

No, items are always ordered by range key (and only within the same hash key).

["For items with a given hash key, DynamoDB stores these items close together, in sorted order by range key."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)

It would probably be easiest to make insertion time the range key (possibly as a secondary index if needed).

Alternatively, you could use [DynamoDB Streams](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to keep track of the last 100 updates somewhere else.