# How to perform Sequential read in dynamo db?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Can we get the items from dynamoDb table in order as they inserted? I tried with Scan api. I am not sure in which order scan is giving the result, but its not in sequential order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is insert order preserved on queries in dynamodb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619718/is-insert-order-preserved-on-queries-in-dynamodb)

Comment: No Mark, I need all the items to be displayed in sequential order. And I should not pass any Partition or Hash  keys to get the items.

Comment: Yes Tejaswi, it is a duplicate of that question. If you read that you will see that DynamoDB doesn't store the insert order, so you cannot retrieve the items in insert order. You have to order the records yourself, using a sort key. There is no other way.

Comment: ok Mark.. Thanks.. :)